# Vba Vlookup with date returns a type mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba, date, vlookup, mismatch

I'm trying to find a value with a Vlookup function in VBA but I get a type mismatch error on the msgbox line.

The lookup_value is tomorrow

Here is the code

```
Sub FINDDATA()
Dim Giov As Date
Dim ImpPag As Variant

Giov = Format(Date + 1, "Short Date")
ImpPag = Application.VLookup(Giov, Range("A5:B9"), 2, False)
MsgBox ImpPag
End Sub
```

And here is the array

```
date        value
05-mar-15   €1.000,00 
12-mar-15   €2.000,00 
19-mar-15   €3.000,00 
26-mar-15   €4.000,00
```

Can I have a little help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, dates are usually stored as a number and only shown as a string in formatting. You can check this by changing the number formatting on the date cells in your spreadsheet.

In this case, the date you are looking up (05/03/2015) is actually stored as 42068. If you declare Giov as a Long data type you can pass the current date + 1 into the lookup. I have added a msgbox so you can see the stored date as a Long Integer before doing the lookup:

```
Sub FINDDATA()
Dim Giov As Long
Dim ImpPag As Variant

Giov = Date + 1
MsgBox Giov
ImpPag = Application.VLookup(Giov, Range("A5:B9"), 2, False)
MsgBox ImpPag
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! Now I have to put the ImpPag value in a email body. Have I to open another question? I already have the non-working code

Comment: Yes, a new question is the best option as it allows people searching for similar issues to find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Declaring a string and formatting that allows you to have the "02-mar-15" format. In your current code type "Debug.Print Giov" below the line where you assign GIOV a value. You will see in the immediate window that GIOV = "5/15/2015" or a date in that style.

```
Sub FINDDATA()
Dim Giov As String
Dim ImpPag As Variant

Giov = Format(Date + 1, "dd-mmm-yy")
ImpPag = Application.VLookup(Giov, Range("A5:B9"), 2, False)
MsgBox ImpPag
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I keep getting the type mismatch error even after your edits...

Comment: Are the values in your "date" column stored as dates?

Comment: Yes they are... Anyway it worked with the suggestion below. Thanks Kyle for your time!